# How to avoid extra new line in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n=int(input())

for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1, i+1):
        print(j, end=' ')
    if(i==n):
        break
    print('\n')
```

This code is giving me output like this

```
1 \n
\n
1 2 \n
\n
1 2 3
```

but i want to get output like this

```
1 2\n
1 2 3
```

how can i do this?

Comment: did you want it to start at the second row, or did you also want the first row of `1`

Comment: Please check out the [ask] page for information on how to improve the quality of your questions. Especially note the recommendation to "Introduce the problem before you post any code" Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print('\n')
```

Since `print` adds a newline to output by default, this line prints a newline (the one you specified), followed by another newline, for a total of two newlines.

If you only want to print one newline, you can remove the explicit newline from your string literal:

```
print('') #or just `print()`
```

... Or you can remove the implicit newline by specifying an end argument:

```
print('\n', end='')
```

Comment: thanks that worked, but is there any way to get rid of the space between number and newline. eg. 1 2 \n  and 1 2\n

Comment: All of your numbers have a space after them because of `print(j, end=' ')`. The quickest fix is to use a conditional to end with a space only if `j` is not the last integer in the row: `print(j, end='' if j == i else '_')`. But if I was writing a solution from scratch, I'd be inclined to skip `end = ...` tricks altogether and just do one join-and-print in the loop: `for i in range(1,n+1): print(" ".join(str(j) for j in range(1, i+1)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
n=int(input())

for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1, i+1):
        print(j, end=' ')
    print()
```

Output:

> ```
> 1 
> 1 2 
> 1 2 3
> ```

Or if you intended to not including the first row:

```
n=int(input())

for i in range(1,n+1):
    if i == 1:
        pass
    else:
        for j in range(1, i+1):
            print(j, end=' ')
        print()
```

Output:

> ```
> 1 2 
> 1 2 3
> ```

Answer (score 0):

What about just the first and last iterations?

```
n=10
for i in range(1,n+1):
    if i==n/n or i==n:
        for j in range(1, i+1): 
            print(j, end=' ') 
        if i==n : 
            break 
        print('\n')
```

I thought this is what your expected output was but I guess not

Output:

```
1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Also the break is pointless. It's not JavaScript, it already knows when to stop the iteration using these methods :)